# How to detect the cpu-peak-inducing transaction/statements (mostly read/select) from mon$... data?

Tags: performance, monitoring, firebird, database-performance, firebird2.1

I can see that the Firebird 2.1 process (on Linux) (for our program) reaches 97% CPU load, the load may be distributed, e.g. the server can have 4 cores and 2 cores are consumed with 97% load and the remaining 2 cores are under normal load (1-10%) from the Firebird process. The bad thing is, that this 97% peak can last half hour, an hour or even longer.

As I understand, then I just need to determine the Firebird transaction and the Firebird attachment (i.e. connection) that has created this peek and then I can just ask the user/software instance, that created this connection/attachment to close his/her program and start anew. When attachment is closed, the Firebird can sense this and Firebird process stops any CPU loads and processes that were assigned to that attachment.

So, my aim is to look on the data from the monitoring tables (mon$...) and to determine the offending transaction/connection.

I came up with the select (for Firebird 2.1):

```sql
select a.mon$user, sa.*, t.*            
  from mon$transactions t           
    left join mon$io_stats s on (t.mon$stat_id=s.mon$stat_id)           
    left join mon$attachments a on (t.mon$attachment_id=a.mon$attachment_id)            
    left join mon$statements sa on (t.mon$transaction_id=sa.mon$transaction_id)         
  where s.mon$page_reads>1000000
```

This SQL seems to be right, but practically the results are misleading. For example, my select returns several entries with a.mon$timestamp that is 4 or even more hours old. I can not believe that there are transactions that are so old and that still are taking resources. The strange thing is that the records have no data from left-joined mon$statements. So, I have some information about long-running transactions, but I have no information about statements that case created or prolonged this transaction. I don't even understand whether such transactions are actually creating the CPU peak or if this data is obsolete.

So, how to correct this SQL (or write completely anew) to find the statements/attachments that is causing CPU % in Firebird 2.1?

Comment: Given you're using an old - no longer supported - version of Firebird, it is also possible you have run into a bug that might be fixed in more recent version of Firebird (e.g. https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/4930, though I don't know if 2.1 was affected by this or not)

Comment: Although not the smartest solution, if you don't have that many different queries, you could give each one a good lookover after reading on common slow queries such as a full table scan on a large table and making sure you are using keys, vertical partitioning, and horizontal partitioning. Of course, things like many joins or a full scan of a tremendous table are likely to be slow among other situations. It might be as simple as looking at your largest tables first to see if any unpartitioned field is used, resulting in a full table scan.

Comment: is your server SuperServer or Classic or SuperClassic ? There might be some housekeeping work, like garbage collection. In some editions (compiler's flags) that housekeepign would be "part of transaction" and in others it would be executed outside of all transactions.

Comment: you may start looking at gstat output about OIT and OAT, see https://www.ibphoenix.com/files/conf2019/05Transactionsinteractionandbestpractices.pdf and there is an article in Russian https://www.ibase.ru/utl/ did not see it translated, and maybe there are commercial tools at ib-aid.com, though they seemingly stopped supporting 2.1 while maybe still do with 2.5

Comment: In all the cases (possible bug #4930, checking for what happened (what report initiated, etc.) at the start of the peak, checking for possible houskeeping works) it would be helpful to have the history of the CPU/cores load by the Firebird process, exactly history with the resolution of some minutes and taken for the period of week or a bit longer. It would be nice if Linux had such history logging tools for the CPU load...

Comment: Firebird 2.5 has TraceAPI that you could used to log statesments and API requests, albeit that API itself puts a significant burden on the engine and can alter its behavior in edge cases. But with FB 2.1... well, i heard people who really needed it were developing their own proxy+log libfbclient.so but never saw such projects going public

Comment: Maybe try a trial of https://ib-aid.com/ibanalyst/  and there is free version at https://www.ibase.ru/summary/ but the free edition stopped with FB 2.0 before FB 2.1

Comment: `I can not believe that there are transactions that are so old and that still are taking resources` - long-running snapshot-level transactions prevent housekeeping and might make fetching records and traversing indices do some snowballing work to enumerate and skip old row versions. That should not be the case with read-only read-committed transactions though, which once was a suggested if unconventional pattern to work with IB/FB. Additionally, long-running transactions (even r/o ones!) may lead to BLOB handles leaks (for example, `LIST` function before FB 2.5), so.... beware.

Comment: Actually it is impossible for Firebird 2.1 superserver to consume two cores up to 97%. Something else must be in equation.

Comment: any UDF's in use ? Also @user13964273 it would be more likely to have Classic in Linux than in Windows. However, AFAIR, in Classic all the housekeeping is done within a transaction so should be seen through monitrogin tables. Perhaps it is just stall transactions leakign somethign during "4 hours"

Comment: @Arioch'The If the classic is used then there is no single "firebird process" and every connection handling process is easily associated with user connection or internal routine by socket thus solving the problem easily.

Comment: @user13964273 there also is "SuperClassic" on Windows, not sure about Linux